# Вектор выводит из файла последний элемент 2 раза

Tags: c++, файлы, вектор

Выводит не всегда 2 раза последний элемент .Если перезапускать может и не вывести 2 раза

```
vector<Student> Group::getValedictorian()
{
    for (Student s : students)
    {
        if (s.getMark() > 0 )
            break;
        else
            students.push_back(s);

    }
    return students;
}
```

Так я вывожу в main функции

```
for (Student s : group.getValedictorian())
    group.printStudent(s);
```

Ввод из файла

```
Group::Group(string filePath)
{
    ifstream studentFile(filePath);

    string lineContents;
    while (!studentFile.eof())
    {
        getline(studentFile, lineContents);

        Student s(lineContents);
        students.push_back(s);
    }
    studentFile.close();

    sort(students.begin(), students.end(), [](Student &s1, Student &s2) 
                                            {
                                                return s1.getMark() > s2.getMark();
                                            });                                 
}

void Group::printStudent(Student student)
{
    cout << "Имя:" << student.getName() << endl;
    cout << "Номер зачётки: " << student.getNtb() << endl;
    cout << "Cр.бал: " << student.getMark() << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

Student::Student(string studentInformation)
{
    stringstream studentStream(studentInformation);
    studentStream >> firstName;
    studentStream >> lastName;
    studentStream >> ntb;
    studentStream >> mark;
}
```

Comment: Ходите по вектору через индексацию, а не через итератор. Возможно, здесь уместнее будет какой-нибудь std::list

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<students.size(); ++i) { if (students[i] ...`

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
 {
  if (students[i].getMark)
   break;
  else
  {
   students[i].push_back(i);
  }
 } пишет что push back не являеться частью класса Student

Comment: Симптомы похожи на классическую ошибку чтения файла `while (!eof)`. Но чтение вы нам не показали. Зачем в заголовке вопроса упомянут файл, если в тексте вопроса ничего связанного с файлами нет?

Comment: выложил как ввожу из файла

Comment: `while (!studentFile.eof())` - как и предсказывалось...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прекратите использовать циклы с предусловием `while (!eof)` при чтении стандартных потоков. Это - почти всегда ошибка. При работе со стандартным потоками в стандартных библиотеках С и С++ у вас вообще не должно быть прямых обращений к eof-состоянию потока, за исключением ряда специальных случаев.

У вас

```
while (!studentFile.eof())
{
  ...
```

Вместо этого должно быть

```
string lineContents;
while (getline(studentFile, lineContents))
{
    Student s(lineContents);
    students.push_back(s);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо работает)

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, вот тут какая-то неувязка. Может, даже UB:

```
for (Student s : students)
{
    if (s.getMark() > 0 )
        break;
    else
        students.push_back(s);
```

Здесь вы добавляете `s` в тот же контейнер, из которого читаете. Он вообще может теоретически вечно добавлять и читать добавленное.

Comment: Student::Student(string studentInformation)
{
 stringstream studentStream(studentInformation);
 studentStream >> firstName;
 studentStream >> lastName;
 studentStream >> ntb;
 studentStream >> mark;
} так вожу в вкласс студент

Comment: так что мне делать?

Comment: Менять логику работы.